# How to declare ELB check protocol to HTTP in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

I am on EKS 1.13. Is there a way to declare health check type on ELB created by Service resource to be http ? It is currently created as TCP protocol. I found service annotations for health check timeouts, intervals, and threshold, but not a way for health check protocol or path.

My config is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: django
    namespace: dev
    labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: django
        app.kubernetes.io/version: dev
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: kubectl
        app: django
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    selector:
        app: django
    ports:
        - port: 80
          targetPort: django-port
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created a Classic load balancer as mentioned in [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/load-balancing.html). You would need to use ALB ingress controller in order to use application load balancer. Using application load balancer, you can have annotations for configuring health check. Please refer [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/alb-ingress.html) and [this document](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-alb-ingress-controller/guide/ingress/annotation/) for more details.

Comment: Yes, what I have is the classic load balancer, and I would like to know if it is possible to configure http check for it.